# how can I get my footer to stay at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I can get my footer to stay at the bottom. Sorry I am still new to this and still learning. If you guys see anything in my code I could do better on just let me know. I was messing around with the positioning a lot. I think the next website I design I will be using flexbox lol. If anyone has any suggestions or some tips for me to do better please let me know. I tried making the body relative and made the footer absolute with bottom set to 0 but that didn't work

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: 'HeadingFont';
    src: url(../fonts/KaushanScript-Regular.otf);
    font-style: normal;
}

body{
    font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* global */
.container{
    width: 100%;
    margin:  5px 0 15px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper{
    padding: 60px 155px ;
    
}


ul{
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type: square;
}

.button_1{
    height: 38px;
    background: #e8491d;
    border: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* header */
header{
background: #35424a;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 30px 10px 0 20px;
min-height: 70px;
border-bottom: #eB491d 3px solid; 
}


header #branding{
    float: left;
    font-family: 'HeadingFont' , 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}
header #branding h1{
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar a{
    color: white;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.navbar{
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.side-nav{
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    background: #35424a;
    opacity: 0.9;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 70px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.side-nav a{
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;

}

.side-nav .btn-close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: -50px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.fas{
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;

}

header .highlight, header .current a{
    color: #e8491d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover{
    color: #cccccc;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*Slider*/
.slider-inner{
    width: 90%;
 height:400px;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 float:left;
 padding:3px;

}

.slider-inner img{
 display:none;
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
}

.slider-inner img.active{
 display:inline-block;
}

.prev,.next{
 float:left;
 margin-top:130px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.prev{
 position:relative;
 margin-right:-45px;
 z-index:100;
}

.next{
 position:relative;
 margin-left:-45px;
 z-index:100;
}

/*Homepage packages*/

#boxes{
    margin-top: 20px;
    
}

#boxes .box{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;

}


#boxes .bronze{
    color: #cd7f32; /*Bronze*/
    text-align: center;
}

#boxes .silver{
    color: #C0C0C0; /*silver*/
}

#boxes .gold{
    color: #CFB53B; /*Gold*/
}

/*Gallery Page*/

    #gallery{
        max-width: 90%;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .image{
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 70%;
        background: #35424a;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .image img{
        width: 200px;
        padding: 10px;

    }

    .image img:hover{
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }




/*Contact Page*/


form {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #35424a;
    color: white;
    width:70%;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #contact{
      width: 90%;
  }

  input[type=text], [type=email], select, textarea{
 width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 resize: vertical;
  }
  
  input[type=submit] {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 30px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 4px;
 cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
  }

  .submit:hover{
    color: black;
    background: rgb(60, 255, 0);
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
  }

  label {
 padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
 display: inline-block;
  }

#contact{
    padding: 50px;
    line-height: 3em;
    
}


/*footer*/

footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #e8491d;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Media Queries*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 940px){

    #wrapper{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #boxes .box{
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
    
    }

    header{
        padding: 10px;
    }

    header nav{
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        }

        .image{
            width: 450px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        
        }

        #gallery{
            width: 100%;
        }

        #contact{
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 100%;
        }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width">
        <title>photagraphy - Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="jqslider/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/01fc06f1b4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="navigation.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="branding">
                    <h1> <span class="highlight">Jamie's</span> photagraphy</h1>
                </div>

                <nav class="navbar">
                    <span class="open-slide">
                        <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
                            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </nav>
                <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="slider-outer">
                    <img src="jqslider/images/arrow-left.png" class="prev" alt="Prev">
                    <div class="slider-inner">
                        <img src="jqslider/images/image1.jpg" class="active">
                        <img src="jqslider/images/image2.jpg">
                        <img src="jqslider/images/image3.jpg">
                        <img src="jqslider/images/image4.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <img src="jqslider/images/arrow-right.png" class="next" alt="Next">
                </div>
            </div>
            <section id="boxes">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h3 class="bronze">Bronze</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Full Day coverage of your wedding.</li>
                            <li>Unlimited Photographers time on Wedding day.</li>
                            <li>Includes 2 hour Engagement session or subtract $200 if not needed.  Includes 25 Digital Photos, two 8x10s and three 5x7s.</li>
                            <li>1 hour Bridal Portrait session with 1 16x20 Canvas and 8x8 photo book with 10 sides or subtract $200 if not needed.</li>
                            <li> Video of photos from Engagement session and Bridal Session to use on your wedding day.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box">
                        <h3 class="silver">Silver</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Up to 8 hours photography for pre-wedding, wedding, and reception photographs.
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Includes 1 hour Engagement session with 1 16x20 print and 2 8x10 prints.  (Subtract $100 if not needed)
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                1 hour Bridal Portrait session with 1 16x20 and 2 8x10 custom prints.  (Subtract $100 if not needed)
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                OPTION -  Engagement Session and Bridal Session or COPY OF 200 DIGITAL PHOTOS of your choice.
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Online proofs.
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box">
                        <h3 class="gold">Gold</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Up to 6 Hours of photography for pre-wedding, wedding, and reception photographs.  (ask about additional time)</li>
                            <li>Online proofs.</li>
                            <li>Two photographers</li>
                            <li>One 16x20 Print!</li>
                            <li>Four 8x10s, Eight 5x7s, 10 4x6s</li>
                            <li>Custom Hard Cover Photo Book.</li>
                            <li>15 full format images of your choice, copyright free.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
        </section>
        </div>
        
        <footer>
            <p>Created by Justin Hamilton. Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out this answer using [CSS Grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) from the older linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52440647/2930477

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses I'll be trying that tonight

Answer (score 0):

Making your footer `position: fixed` will help you achieve this. You may have to watch out for other elements near the bottom colliding and overlapping. You can use margins to help with that. Also, using a high `z-index` will prevent other elements from being displayed over top of it.

[You can read more about fixed positioning here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HeadingFont';
  src: url(../fonts/KaushanScript-Regular.otf);
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* global */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0 15px 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  padding: 60px 155px;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: square;
}

.button_1 {
  height: 38px;
  background: #e8491d;
  border: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* header */

header {
  background: #35424a;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px 10px 0 20px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #eB491d 3px solid;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'HeadingFont', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

header #branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.side-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  background: #35424a;
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 70px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.side-nav a {
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -50px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fas {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
}

header .highlight,
header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Slider*/

.slider-inner {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
}

.slider-inner img {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.slider-inner img.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

.prev,
.next {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.next {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
}


/*Homepage packages*/

#boxes {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#boxes .box {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#boxes .bronze {
  color: #cd7f32;
  /*Bronze*/
  text-align: center;
}

#boxes .silver {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  /*silver*/
}

#boxes .gold {
  color: #CFB53B;
  /*Gold*/
}


/*Gallery Page*/

#gallery {
  max-width: 90%;
  padding: 50px;
}

.image {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 70%;
  background: #35424a;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

.image img {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.image img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}


/*Contact Page*/

form {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #35424a;
  color: white;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#contact {
  width: 90%;
}

input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
}

.submit:hover {
  color: black;
  background: rgb(60, 255, 0);
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
}

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#contact {
  padding: 50px;
  line-height: 3em;
}


/*footer*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #e8491d;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}


/*Media Queries*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #boxes .box {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  header {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  header nav {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
  }
  .image {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #gallery {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #contact {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width">
  <title>photagraphy - Welcome</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="jqslider/js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/01fc06f1b4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="navigation.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="branding">
        <h1> <span class="highlight">Jamie's</span> photagraphy</h1>
      </div>

      <nav class="navbar">
        <span class="open-slide">
                        <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
                            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                        </a>
                    </span>
      </nav>
      <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
        <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slider-outer">
        <img src="jqslider/images/arrow-left.png" class="prev" alt="Prev">
        <div class="slider-inner">
          <img src="jqslider/images/image1.jpg" class="active">
          <img src="jqslider/images/image2.jpg">
          <img src="jqslider/images/image3.jpg">
          <img src="jqslider/images/image4.jpg">
        </div>
        <img src="jqslider/images/arrow-right.png" class="next" alt="Next">
      </div>
    </div>
    <section id="boxes">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
          <h3 class="bronze">Bronze</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Full Day coverage of your wedding.</li>
            <li>Unlimited Photographers time on Wedding day.</li>
            <li>Includes 2 hour Engagement session or subtract $200 if not needed. Includes 25 Digital Photos, two 8x10s and three 5x7s.</li>
            <li>1 hour Bridal Portrait session with 1 16x20 Canvas and 8x8 photo book with 10 sides or subtract $200 if not needed.</li>
            <li> Video of photos from Engagement session and Bridal Session to use on your wedding day.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
          <h3 class="silver">Silver</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>
              Up to 8 hours photography for pre-wedding, wedding, and reception photographs.
            </li>
            <li>
              Includes 1 hour Engagement session with 1 16x20 print and 2 8x10 prints. (Subtract $100 if not needed)
            </li>
            <li>
              1 hour Bridal Portrait session with 1 16x20 and 2 8x10 custom prints. (Subtract $100 if not needed)
            </li>
            <li>
              OPTION - Engagement Session and Bridal Session or COPY OF 200 DIGITAL PHOTOS of your choice.
            </li>
            <li>
              Online proofs.
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
          <h3 class="gold">Gold</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Up to 6 Hours of photography for pre-wedding, wedding, and reception photographs. (ask about additional time)</li>
            <li>Online proofs.</li>
            <li>Two photographers</li>
            <li>One 16x20 Print!</li>
            <li>Four 8x10s, Eight 5x7s, 10 4x6s</li>
            <li>Custom Hard Cover Photo Book.</li>
            <li>15 full format images of your choice, copyright free.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>Created by Justin Hamilton. Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Use:

```
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4rem;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Your Css had:

```
footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #e8491d;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your footer fixed

make sure you add **z-index** value so that other element don't overlaps the footer.

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#content {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;    /* Footer height */
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
 </head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
   <div id="content">
     <!-- all other page content -->
   </div>
   <footer id="footer"></footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```